Prediction and Work
I've had this idea that if you can predict something, you can theoretically extract work from it. For instance if you know a certain mass is going from point A to point B, you can place something in the way that it bumps into, which causes it to lift a mass. If you know that hydrogen gas is going to be the product of a certain reaction, you can collect it in a balloon or something.
This seems to me to be something that's obviously true intuitively, but then I realized I'm not sure if I have a great physical explanation for it. Are there any established ways of describing this? Is it accepted as true by physicists generally? or is there a weaker version of the statement that's accepted?
If I want to use it as a part of a rigorous argument for something (we can predict this, therefore we can theoretically extract energy from it), what needs to be in place for it to be accepted as true? Is there a certain principle I can point to?  Would it just be accepted as theoretically true, or would I have to provide the mechanism?
I also know if you think about the entropy of a probability density function of a certain system's states, unless it's uniform, there's always some theoretically higher-entropy probability density function.  I would say that knowing that the probability density function is not uniform among a system's states is akin to "prediction".
Is it valid to say that if you know that the probability density function of system's states is not uniform, that you can theoretically extract energy from it?
I guess this is a sort of generalization of Maxwell's demon.  Can we say that for any system, a Maxwell's demon could arrange it into a lower-entropy state?

is this a jam session? Let me summarize some of your question: you postulate something that you think it is "obviously true intuitively" and ask if what you're postulating is currently accepted by the physics community (how could anyone know anything about your dream?)

I predict my keyboard will sit motionless on my desk unless disturbed. How do you propose to extract energy from that?

"if you can predict something, you can theoretically extract work from it." If it is an active prediction (i.e. something will happen, rather than something will not happen as in @NuclearHoagie 's example), it seems true.... If you can predict the stock market tomorrow, you can make certain money, if you can predict water will flow down a particular path, you can extract work from it...

@James There is no fundamental different between a "positive" and "negative" prediction. In some arbitrary reference frame, my keyboard is merrily sailing through space at a constant velocity. In the desk frame, I can predict the keyboard won't go anywhere; in the reference frame of a car driving past, I can predict I'll observe the keyboard passing by at 40mph.

@NuclearHoagie how about adding the condition "if you can predict something will happen in your own reference frame, you can theoretically extract work from it"? If I can predict that water will flow down a particular path in my frame of reference, then I can certainly extract work from it?

@basics --- It's basically a generalization of maxwell's demon.  Not something I completely made up.  Maxwell's Demon is accepted as valid.  Of course that makes sense because there's a specific mechanism defined, but people apply the concept elsewhere without defining mechanisms.  So I wonder how far you can stretch it, and how to justify your stretching of it.  When people stretch it, are they relying on some established principle?

@NuclearHoagie - light a match and take it to that location along with a thermoelectric generator?

@basics -- also yes, it's kind of a jam session :)


I've had this idea that if you can predict something, you can theoretically extract work from it.

I don't think that is always true. For example, if you have a closed system (i.e. perfectly isolated from its environment) consisting of two containers of gas at the same pressure and temperature then you can predict that if you connect the two containers they will both remain at the same pressure and temperature i.e. there will be no net movement of gas from one container to the other and no spontaneous flow of heat from one container to the other. But you cannot extract work from such a system.

Upvoting. I'd say "closed and isolated system", so that no heat exchange (that can be later converted to work) can occur

Thank you for the response.  Let's imagine you have a mechanism uses the momentum of particles going into container B to lift a weight, and uses the momentum of particles going into container A to trigger a "ratchet" which locks the weight at the current level and resets the mechanism to lift the weight from the particles going into container B.  As long as there's a temperature above a certain threshold (required to lift the weight), you should be able to extract the energy, correct?

That doesn't discount your response I don't think, I guess it just qualifies it... That as long as there's energy within the system, knowing the state of it can allow it to be extracted, but knowing that the system has no energy (which I guess is equivalent to saying it has a uniform PDF across the states in question) doesn't allow you to extract energy.

@davidmnoll The mechanism that you are describing is called a "Brownian ratchet". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_ratchet - especially the section on why it fails.

@gandalf61 -- thanks for that.  I'm curious if the proofs for why it fails rely on indistinguishability of the particles?  Since I'm assuming distinguishability between A & B particles in my hypothetical, this would invalidate any proofs resting on the opposite assumption.  Of course in practice we can't distinguish them so in practice there would be no extractable work.  But the important thing this is getting at is whether information about an asymmetry inherently corresponds to free energy.

It has nothing to do with "prediction" If something moves it has kinetic energy, you can change it to any other kind of energy. Thats how one uses moving water or air or a dynamo on a bicycle.Same with chemical energy (getting hydrogen gas)
So what you say is just transforming energy in an other form.

Thank you for the response.  My thought is: But if you don't know where the water or bicycle are going, then you can't predictably do anything with them.

If you don't know where something is going, how will you do a prediction? <if you put you generator outside the stream, you "prediction" was wrong and you don't get any work. so what precisely do you call "prediction" if not knowing in advance?

Yes, I guess that's the thing.  "Prediction" needs a precise definition.  I would suggest you're "predicting" something if you're proposing a PDF across the states you're considering, and the PDF you're proposing is something other than uniform.  So then you need to consider the accuracy of the prediction.
